# Change Content from div container if it is smaller than XYZ px

Tags: html, css, slideshow, responsive

I have a little problem with my website. If the screen of the device smaller than xyz px the slideshow doesn´t work anymore. And I want to be there a picture instead of the slideshow.

The slideshow that I am using is Owl Carousel
How can I do this?

Comment: It seems working here https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/. Could you check what's the difference with your CSS? Probably you added some styles which broke OwlCarousel responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **CSS media rules**.
[CSS3 @media Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Both elements (image and carrousel) must be in your HTML code.
Without the appropiate CSS media query, both would be displayed, but if you provide the correct rules, **you can hide/display the desired element, under each diferent screen size.**

```
.my_carrousel{ display: block; }
.my_image{ display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .my_carrousel{ display: none; }
    .my_image{ display: block; }
}
```